# Curious case of missing links - Click To Edit links not visible in List/Library settings

Tags: 2010

We have two SharePoint Web Application (IIS sites) one running on http port 80 and other on port 1234.

Web app on port 1234 has one site collection and few sub sites, document libraries, lists etc.

On this site collection, a weird issue is coming. If library/list settings page is opened, any links to open/edit Column names, view names or content name are not visible.

This effectively means user can create additional columns, but cannot edit them later because there are no visible links.

Even if a new list is created anywhere on this site collection, these links to listedit.aspx, ViewEdit.aspx, ManageContentType.aspx do not seem to appear as seen in screen shot.

So far I've checked that: listedit.aspx, ViewEdit.aspx, ManageContentType.aspx are not modified by comparing them from layouts folder of clean build SP2010 standalone installation

Any clues are appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen this before. I'm guessing it's not SharePoint breaking, but (hopefully) something in your masterpage customization?

If you hover over them and try clicking they don't work? Try using the IE Dev Toolbar (http://davidlozzi.com/2013/05/08/a-non-developers-intro-to-the-developer-toolbar-element-inspection/) and see if you can see the HTML elements, then check their associated CSS, all explained in that post. I gotta believe they're there ;)

Comment: It was a CSS problem. Additional css applied in master page. Removing this css makes links appear and work as normal.